# Rewrite a call to su-exec with su or similar?

Tags: bash, su, escape-characters

In this [bash script](https://github.com/31z4/zookeeper-docker/blob/d5d320f94212691bd6e60326e45c152ac6784210/3.4.10/docker-entrypoint.sh) under Linux Alpine they have (line 8):

```
exec su-exec "$ZOO_USER" "$0" "$@"
```

As far as I know, `su-exec` is however an [Apache httpd dependecy](https://serverfault.com/questions/402418/how-to-change-suexec-root-directory-from-var-www-to-home) - can I avoid it installing it under Ubuntu and use some more plain alternative?

I have tested so far:

```
 su -c "$0 $@" $ZOO_USER
```

But then this Docker command shows that I might have some sort of escaping/quotes error,

```
CMD ["zkServer.sh", "start-foreground"]
```

resulting in the following output. What is the difference to the original, which works fine?

```
No passwd entry for user 'start-foreground'
```

Comment: duplicate of: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/interference-of-docker-cmd-with-su-works-with-su-exec-but-not-with-su

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As colleagues at DevOps SE have pointed out, the proper usage of ´su´ should be:

```
su -c "$0" "$ZOO_USER" "$@"
```